# Excel-change cell formula dependent on input to another cell

Tags: format

I hope I'll be clear.
C13 has a Formula =E13/1.21
I want that if F13 has an X then C13 should have =E13

E13 has the base price of the item
I need C13 to show the price including VAT (%21 here) unless there is an X in F13, then C13 would show the same as E13
thx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you have tried so far. We're happy to help if you have trouble with some programming task, but this site is not a code-writing service (or, more appropriately here, a formula-writing service).

Comment: i am looking for a formula-writing service and if this site can't help me then i willl look elsewhere. thx

Comment: It's not a "service" of any kind. We're all volunteers, helping each other with coding problems. But most of us aren't willing to do somebody else's work for free.